# Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() returning 'undefined'

Tags: meteor

I have a running Meteor application on a Fedora 18 workstation.  The meteor web application appears to be functioning correctly without errors in the web console.  When I try to run the following in the Web console it returns undefined.

```
Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()
```

According to the documentation and other StackOverflow answers this should work.  I have used both FireFox and Chrome to test this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to create this `ObjectID()` with `new` ?

Please try :

```
var _id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID();
console.log(_id);
```

Comment: That's not the right syntax to create a Collection. It's `new Meteor.Collection("collectionName");`.

Comment: @AndrewMao This is not a syntax for creating Collections.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to var id = new ObjectID().  Which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the parentheses.

```
Meteor.Collection.ObjectID
```

Comment: When I do that it returns the function definition.[16:10:09.138] (function (hexString) {
  //random-based impl of Mongo ObjectID
  var self = this;
  if (hexString) {
    hexString = hexString.toLowerCase();
    if (!LocalCollection._looksLikeObjectID(hexString)) {
      throw new Error("Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID");
    }
    // meant to work with _.isEqual(), which relies on structural equality
    self._str = hexString;
  } else {
    self._str = Random.hexString(24);
  }
})

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo** replaced **Meteor.Collection**. Mongo.ObjectID follows the same API as the Node MongoDB driver ObjectID class.

```
var _id = new Mongo.ObjectID();
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id